# Where should Tensorflow serving be cloned to?

Tags: python, git, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've installed Tensorflow but now wish to productionize my model.

So I'm trying to follow this guide:

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/setup.md

Does Tensorflow serving run along side Tensor flow?

If so where should I clone the the repo to so that the packages can be seen on the python library path please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has not been developed as of 03/13/2017.  See [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/52).  It says there has not been a binary release of tensorflow serving yet so the only way you can import the packages is by cloning the repo and doing development inside of the cloned project.

To answer your question about serving running alongside Tensorflow:  the tensorflow module inside of serving is the tensorflow project, so basically tensorflow_serving comes with its own tensorflow.